# overriding jquery plugin which uses a custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, overriding, custom-data-attribute

I am currently using [Jquery Fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) in my project which accepts attribute e.g. `data-type="iframe"` to say that I want to open this link in an Iframe.

I am developing another plugin which also want to use `data-type` attribute. Is there a general way to override the data attribute in another plugin without modifying the source of that plugin (I mean modifying it using an external script)? For example I want say the fancybox use `data-type2` instead of `data-type` and let the `data-type` in use for my own plugin.

Comment: Unless the library allows you to change the data attribute name in settings, then no you cannot change it without changing the source of the library, which is a very bad idea for a whole host of reasons. If you want both to work together you need to change what *you* have control of, which is the data attribute name that your plugin uses.

Comment: WHy not just change your own plugin which you have control over - would seem to make more sense

Comment: This question is just a simple sample to know how can I override a plugin. In fact I am afride how to manage multiple plugins if they used same data attributes. @Pete